# in python for loop,, jump over values

Tags: python, for-loop, range

```
time=0
gold=0
level=1
for time in range(100):
  gold+=level
  if gold>20*level:
    level+=1
    time+=10
```

with this program gold is added until it reaches a critical amount, then it takes 20s to upgrade a mine so it produces more gold. i'd like to skip those 20s (or 20 steps) in the loop? this works in c++, i'm not sure how to do it in python.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't do it in `range(100)`. The `for` loop doesn't offer a way to skip ahead like that; `time` will be set to the next value in the list regardless of what you change it to in the body of the loop. Use a `while` loop instead, e.g.

```
time = 0
while time < 100:
   gold += level
   if gold > 20 * level:
      level +=1
      time += 10
   time += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`time` will continually get overwritten each loop iteration, so `time+=10` will not have the desired effect. You can convert the loop back into a C style loop using `while` and explicit mutation of the `time` variable or you could be fancy and setup an iterator which allows skipping ahead arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment to `time` on the last line has no effect.  At the top of the loop, `time` is immediately assigned to the next value yielded by `range`.  But why is this a loop at all, can't you just do the calculations outright?